# Como implementar um método abstrato com uma classe genérica em C#

Tags: c#, .net, herança, genéricos

Estou criando uma Factory funcional onde eu defino qual é o tipo de saída dela e quais são os métodos de implementação obrigatórios.

Com essa implementação, quando tento usar o objeto `obj` dentro da função que faz todo processo de factory daquele objeto, ele não consegue interpretá-lo como sendo do tipo Bar.

> A idéia é que eu possa ter a mesma declaração `FooFactory.build()` para múltiplos tipos, mudando apenas a implementação encapsulada e sempre tendo como retorno uma `Foo`.

Como resolver?

Meu código está ficando assim:

```
public abstract class Factory<T> where T : class {
    public abstract T Build<U>(U obj) where U : class;
}
public class Quadrado {
    public int Largura { get; set; }
    public int Altura { get; set;}
}
public class Retangulo {
    public int Largura { get; set; }
    public int Altura { get; set; }
}
public class QuadradoFactory: Factory<Quadrado> {
    public override Quadrado Build<Retangulo>(Retangulo o) => 
        new Quadrado() { Largura = o.Largura, Altura = o.Largura };
}
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var f = new QuadradoFactory();
        var r = new Retangulo(){ Largura=2, Altura=4 };
        var q = f.Build<Retangulo>(r);

        System.Console.WriteLine(
            "Largura: " + q.Largura + 
            "Altura: " + q.Altura
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hoje não é possível especializar o tipo genérico no método herdado. Isto chama-se covariância. Uma solução óbvia é fazer o tipo base restringir para um tipo que atenda exatamente o contrato de `Retangulo`, o que pode fazer até a genericidade nem ser necessária.

Ou você transfere a genericidade para o tipo:

```
public abstract class Factory<T, U> where T : class  where U : class {
    public abstract T Build(U obj);
}
public class Quadrado {
    public int Largura { get; set; }
    public int Altura { get; set;}
}
public class Retangulo {
    public int Largura { get; set; }
    public int Altura { get; set; }
}
public class QuadradoFactory: Factory<Quadrado, Retangulo> {
    public override Quadrado Build(Retangulo o) => new Quadrado() { Largura = o.Largura, Altura = o.Altura };
}
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var f = new QuadradoFactory();
        var r = new Retangulo(){ Largura = 2, Altura = 4 };
        var q = f.Build(r);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Largura: " + q.Largura + " Altura: " + q.Altura);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/pMvd0E). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JEnMbl). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Generics/CovarianceOnMethod.cs).

A outra solução é jogar fora a segurança de tipo (prefiro não):

```
public abstract class Factory<T> where T : class {
    public abstract T Build<U>(U obj) where U : class;
}
public class Quadrado {
    public int Largura { get; set; }
    public int Altura { get; set;}
}
public class Retangulo {
    public int Largura { get; set; }
    public int Altura { get; set; }
}
public class QuadradoFactory: Factory<Quadrado> {
    public override Quadrado Build<U>(U o) {
        var obj = o as Retangulo;
        if (obj == null) return null;
        return new Quadrado() { Largura = obj.Largura, Altura = obj.Altura };
    }
}
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var f = new QuadradoFactory();
        var r = new Retangulo(){ Largura = 2, Altura = 4 };
        var q = f.Build<Retangulo>(r);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Largura: " + q.Largura + " Altura: " + q.Altura);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/6EWibE). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wPpNyq). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Generics/CovarianceByCasting.cs).

Comment: Não, no modelo que você mostrou você passa uma string. fazendo dessa forma ele realmente entendeu mas se eu utilizo uma classe composta ele não funciona.

Comment: Classe é classe, não existe classe que é composta ou não composta. O que você perguntou eu respondi, se o problema real é outro não está na pergunta. Eu não tenho como responder porque a pergunta não mostra isto.

Comment: ok, reformulei a pergunta

Comment: Mas eu já respondi o que foi perguntado. Agora não sei se eu tenho a resposta, se tenho tempo pra ver isso. Agora você está fazendo outra pergunta.

Comment: Mudei a resposta, mas não faça isto, complica pra quem respondeu.

Comment: creio que não tenha me expressado direito na primeira vez. realmente o que eu preciso é a segunda opção visto que eu posso ter múltiplos métodos Build, baseando apenas no tipo de informação passada.

Comment: Aí eu acho melhor pensar em outra coisa, deixa o código sem robustez, com carga cognitiva para lidar. Se eu entendi direito. Se for outra coisa, nem rola, não vai dar certo. Claramente este não é o problema real, mas a solução nem deve ser esta para o problema real.